# How correctly require in Jest file ? (with a module pattern js file)

Tags: jestjs, require

Probably a stupid question

I start using JEST for testing.

I have my js app :

```
var app={ init:function{ //some code}, ... }
module.exports = app;
```

And my app.test.js :

```
const {app} = require('../js/index.js')

test('type of variable', () => {
  expect(typeof app.someFunction(app.someVar)).toBe("'number");
});
```

And I have the classic error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'someFunction' of undefined
```

It seem very stupid, but I never understand clearly these require on client side...
It work perfectly with the Jest getStarted example
[image]

My arbo is

```
-js
----index.js
-tests
----app.text.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module.exports = app
```

The above line returns `object {}`, and you are trying to pick `app` from object in your destructing line `var {app}`

Remove `{}`

```js
const app = require('../js/index.js')

test('type of variable', () => {
  expect(typeof app.someFunction(app.someVar)).toBe("'number");
});
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks

Comment: Your welcome, Happy to help. Accept if that works for you :)